# Skipping a term in a string (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, label

With the below code. I basically want to skip the first label and print the second label:

```
<results>

    <status>OK</status>

    <usage>By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html</usage>

    <totalTransactions>1</totalTransactions>
    <language>english</language>
    <taxonomy>
        <element>
            <label>/food and drink/desserts and baking</label>
            <score>0.995261</score>
        </element>
        <element>
            <confident>no</confident>
            <label>/food and drink/food/candy and sweets</label>
            <score>0.0748896</score>
        </element>
        <element>
            <confident>no</confident>
            <label>/food and drink/vegan</label>
            <score>0.0267116</score>
        </element>
    </taxonomy>
</results>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<results>

    <status>ERROR</status>

    <statusInfo>unsupported-text-language</statusInfo>

    <usage>By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html</usage>

    <totalTransactions>1</totalTransactions>
    <language>spanish</language>
</results>
science/weather<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<results>

    <status>OK</status>

    <usage>By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html</usage>

    <totalTransactions>1</totalTransactions>
    <language>english</language>
    <taxonomy>
        <element>
            <label>/science/weather</label>
            <score>1</score>
        </element>
        <element>
            <confident>no</confident>
            <label>/shopping/toys/dolls</label>
            <score>2.22317e-05</score>
        </element>
        <element>
            <confident>no</confident>
            <label>/shopping/toys/puppets</label>
            <score>2.22317e-05</score>
        </element>
    </taxonomy>
</results>
style and fashion/clothing/shirts<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<results>
```

So I would end up with "/shopping/toys/puppets." Does anyone know how I can ignore the first labels to get the 2nd? Thanks!

Here's my code so far:

```
 file='C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\cloudsight.txt'
 f = File.open(file, "r")
 f.each_line {|line|

 tstart = 'name"=>"'
 tstop = '"'
 term = line[/#{tstart}(.*?)#{tstop}/m, 1]

 url = 'http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls'
 service = '/text/TextGetRankedTaxonomy'
 apikey = '?apikey= ENTER API KEY'
 thething = '&text='
 #termencoded = URI::encode(term)
 termencoded = URI::encode(term.to_s)
 fullurl = url + service + apikey + thething + termencoded

 sleep 1

 opener = open(fullurl, 'Accept-Encoding' => '') {|f| f.read }
 lstart = '<label>/'
 lstop = '</label>'
 label = opener[/#{lstart}(.*?)#{lstop}/m, 1]
 print label
```

Comment: I've added my code to the question. I've just tried to pull from the html code.

Comment: It would be much easier if this was a valid XML document.

Comment: I would ensure its valid XML and then use the nokogiri library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it another way. I printed all the strings I needed manually:

## ALCHEMY

```
 file='C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\cloudsight.txt'
 f = File.open(file, "r")
 f.each_line {|line|
   
 tstart = 'name"=>"'
 tstop = '"'
 term = line[/#{tstart}(.*?)#{tstop}/m, 1]

 url = 'http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls'
 service = '/text/TextGetRankedTaxonomy'
 apikey = '?apikey= ENTER API KEY
 thething = '&text='
 #termencoded = URI::encode(term)
 termencoded = URI::encode(term.to_s)
 fullurl = url + service + apikey + thething + termencoded
 
 sleep 1
 
 opener = open(fullurl, 'Accept-Encoding' => '') {|f| f.read }
  
 lstart = '<label>/'
 lstop = '</label>'
 label = opener[/#{lstart}(.*?)#{lstop}/m, 1]
 print label

 print ","


 cstart = '<score>'
 cstop = '</score>'
 confidence = opener[/#{cstart}(.*?)#{cstop}/m, 1]  
 print confidence

 lstart2 = '</label>'
 lstop2 = '</taxonomy>'
 label2 = opener[/#{lstart2}(.*?)#{lstop2}/m, 1]
 label22 = label2.to_s
 
 print ","

 lstart22 = '<label>/'
 lstop22 = '</label>'
 label23 = label22[/#{lstart22}(.*?)#{lstop22}/m, 1]
 print label23

 cstart22 = '</score>'
 cstop22 = '</taxonomy>'
 confidence22 = opener[/#{cstart22}(.*?)#{cstop22}/m, 1] 

 print ","

 cstart23 = '<score>'
 cstop23 = '</score>'
 confidence23 = confidence22[/#{cstart23}(.*?)#{cstop23}/m, 1] 
 print confidence23

 lstart30 = '</element>'
 lstop30 = '</taxonomy>'
 label30 = opener[/#{lstart30}(.*?)#{lstop30}/m, 1]

 lstart31 = '</element>'
 lstop31 = '</element>'
 label31 = label30[/#{lstart31}(.*?)#{lstop31}/m, 1]
 

 lstart32 = '<label>/'
 lstop32 = '</label>'
 label32 = label31[/#{lstart32}(.*?)#{lstop32}/m, 1]
 print label32

 print ","

 cstart32 = '<score>'
 cstop32 = '</score>'
 confidence32 = label31[/#{cstart32}(.*?)#{cstop32}/m, 1]
 print confidence32
```